# how to add all integers between two numbers in Java?

Tags: java

so I made a simple sum app in android studio

```
public void add(View view){
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    Float firstNumber = Float.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
    Float secondNumber = Float.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());

    Float sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;

    editText3.setText(sum.toString());
}
```

How should I change this in order to sum all integers between two numbers
for example if Text1 = 1 and Text2 = 5 then the sum should be 1+2+3+4+5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public void add(View view){
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    int firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
    int secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
    {
        sum+=i;
    }

    editText3.setText("" + sum);
}
```

Comment: I get a error message in 'toString' from (sum.toString());

Comment: Ah well, I have fixed that. I have changed Integer object to int, which does not have toString method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to find the sum

```
int sum(int smallest, int largest) {
    int length = (largest - smallest + 1);

    int sum = length * (smallest + largest) / 2;

    return sum;
}
```

you can call like this,

```
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

int sum = sum(firstNumber, secondNumber);

editText3.setText(sum.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int firstNumber, secondNumber;
    float ans = 0;  
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         ans = 0;
        firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
        secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

        for (; firstNumber <= secondNumber; firstNumber++) {
            ans += firstNumber;
        }
        editText3.setText(ans + "");
    }
});
```